# Trouble using a data constructor defined in an imported file

Tags: haskell

Say I have a queue implementation in a file and wanted to import it to work in a main file. I'm having trouble figuring out how to properly do so without getting a constructor error.

Say I have this in one file `Queue1.hs`

```
module Queue1 (Queue, mtq, ismt, addq, remq) where
data Queue a = Queue1 [a] deriving (Show)
-- multiple methods defined . . .
```

Then in my main file say I have:

```
import Queue1
```

And wanted to do this, which adds a list to the beginning of the `Queue`:

```
addq :: [a] -> Queue a -> Queue a
addq xs q = undefined
```

How exactly would I create the function so that I can use the `Queue` methods defined in another file?

I have created the following variations with no success:

```
adds xs (Queue q) = (xs:q)
error: Not in scope: data constructor ‘Queue’
   |
13 | adds xs (Queue q) = (xs:q)
```

I also tried defining another `Queue` in the file which didn't work:

```
data Queue a = Queue3 [a] deriving Show 
adds :: [a] -> Queue a -> Queue as
adds xs (Queue3 q) = Queue3(xs:q)

error:
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘Queue’
    It could refer to
       either ‘Queue1.Queue’,
              imported from ‘Queue1’ at lab3.hs:4:1-13
              (and originally defined at Queue1.hs:17:1-41)
           or ‘Main.Queue’, defined at lab3.hs:9:1
```

Can anyone point to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data constructors are not exported for a type by default. This allows us to write abstract types which can only be manipulated via a well-defined interface. A well-known example of this is [`Data.Map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.4.0.0/docs/Data-Map.html), which is internally a funny tree-like structure with lots of internal invariants, but the constructor isn't exported because the devs don't want you poking around and making invalid maps.

However, in this case, you want to export `Queue`, both the type *and* the constructor, as it looks like you want users to be able to construct and pattern match against your type. The syntax to export a specific constructor is

```
module Queue1 (Queue(Queue1), mtq, ismt, addq, remq) where
```

If you want to export all of the constructors (and record fields, if there are any), then you can use the shortcut wildcard syntax

```
module Queue1 (Queue(..), mtq, ismt, addq, remq) where
```

In this case, that's equivalent to the first example, but if you had several constructors, then `..` would export them all.

Comment: This clears things up for me in terms of exporting the constructor, but i'm still unsure how I would properly apply a queue to the 'addq' function. I formatted the module correctly, but am still getting errors when i try and define the function.

Comment: @subprimeloads At a glance, the result type of `addq` should be `Queue a`  (as the type of the queue doesn't change), and its implementation should use `++` rather than `:` (you want to concatenate lists rather than to prepend a single element). There's also a subtler question about whether you really want to add to the beginning of the queue. That would be better dealt with in a separate question, though.